# How to remove some part of text in the first index of php array

Tags: php

This is my array in php
$a is my array

```
 Array
    (
        [0] =>  class="date-display-single">24-Feb-2013
        [2] => 11:35
        [3] => AM
    )
```

How do I remove `class="date-display-single">` from `array[0]`?

Comment: How are you getting that array in the first place?

Comment: Let's get this clear: do you want to remove the entire first element, or do you want to strip a certain piece out of the first element ?

Answer (score 2):

Several ways... But the simplest one is to do:

```
 $a[0] = str_replace('class="data-display-single">', '', $a[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple statement should do exactly that:

```
$a[0] = substr($a[0], strpos($a[0], '>') + 1);
```

That said, it all depends on how you ended up with that array in the first place; it seems things can be fixed higher up in the code.

Comment: `it seems things can be fixed higher up in the code.` +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

there you are:

```
$a[0] = str_replace('class="date-display-single">','',$a[0]);
```

but i would do it in the string, before you explode your date string. no in the array after

Answer (score 0):

Check out [unset()](http://php.net/unset)

You could try something like:

```
unset($a[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 str_replace('class="date-display-single">', '', $a[0]);
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors, and your 'haystack' doesn't relate to the question at all.

Comment: Why vote down? Explain please

Comment: And what are those errors? The person is that eligible to know the difference between single and double quotes

Comment: Because you had a wrong answer earlier and later on decided to change it to the one who got upvoted. Anyway, i down voted on the moment you had the wrong answer. That's why

Comment: No, I deleted the answer because the same was downvoted. My answer is still the same :/

Comment: Seems like i didn't even downvoted this post, was indeed another one. Don't know why others downvoted it though.. :(

Comment: @Ahmed First, I didn't down-voted anything here and found it astonishing why all the posts were down-voted. But you had a syntax error in your post. Note the difference between `"` and `'` quotes. I've edited this

Comment: @hek2mgl yes that was a mistake and I also noticed that all the answers were down voted, thanks for editing :)